# Send rows on columns with mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

i have 1 table, what i need is have only 1 row per object like group objects on a single row:
[image: From this]

This is what i need in the result of query

[image]

I have use something like SELECT object, study, element FROM mytable GROUP BY object, but i still missing something to

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation for the [GROUP_CONCAT() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [aggregate function `group_concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select
    object,
    group_concat(study order by study separator ',') study,
    group_concat(element order by element separator ',') element
from mytable
group by object
```

You might want to adjust the `order by` clause according to your actual requirement. You might also want to consider the using the `distinct` clause if you want to avoid duplicates in the resulting string.